# Remove values that don't match a list

Tags: r

I'm trying to clean up a US State field that contains some invalid entries so I can  coerce to a factor with 50 levels and create dummy variables for each state.

Take this sample dataframe for instance:

```
   ID  State  
 1  1    PA  
 2  2  <NA>  
 3  3    MD  
 4  4    VA  
 5  5    VD
```

I would like to remove any values that aren't valid US state abbreviations ("VD" in this example) and replace them with NAs.

I tried:

```
df$State[df$State!=one_of(state.abb)] <- NA
```

but it returns:

```
Error: Variable context not set
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `df$State[!(df$State %in% state.abb)] <- NA`

Comment: `one_of` is a `dplyr` function meant to be used within the `dplyr` `select` function. That's why, if not inside `select` you need to use some other method.

Comment: Thanks @Jaap ! Great solution. To anyone who finds this thread, I would also suggest 2 additional steps: 
1. using `df$State <- trimws(df$State)` to make sure you're not removing valid states with surrounding whitespace.  
2. using `states <- c(state.abb, "DC")` if you want to include DC as a valid state abbreviation.

Comment: thank you @Ryan as well! I suspected as much but I couldn't find a concrete answer as to why one_of was returning the out of context error. Now I know!

Comment: This question should be marked as closed. Michael you should self-answer or @Ryan please submit your answer so that it can be closed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$State[!(df$State %in% state.abb)] <- NA
```

answer provided by @Jaap